# How to make a iso boot while turning on PC

Tags: boot, iso-image

How to make an ISO file I have in the internal storage of my computer boot as the PC starts up or like an actual bootable ISO as a boot option in the boot manager so that it boots up as a bootable disk or USB

Comment: You would need to disable Secure Boot and then change the Boot Order, both in BIOS.

Comment: You could also write that ISO file on some USB key, and configure BIOS to boot from it

Comment: Use a tool such as Rufus, https://rufus.ie/, or Universal Boot USB Installer, https://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/, to make it easier.